# Probability distribution of product of random variables using delta function

Tags: probability

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are independent random variables, uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Define a new random variable $X = AB$. I would like to determine the probability density function $\bar{P}(x)$ for $X$.

I know how to determine $\bar{P}(x)$ by computing the area under contours of constant $x$. The result is
$$\bar{P}(x)=-\ln x.$$

However, I heard that there is a more general formula:
$$\bar{P}(x)=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}dadb\delta(x-ab),$$
where $\delta$ is Dirac delta function. But it appears that there is a mistake in this formula, because when I computed it, I got zero.

I just want to ask what is the correct form of the equation? And what is this type of problem called?

Comment: "find the probability distribution $P(ab)$" is kind of senseless if $ab$ is a real number (and so it seems). You can at most interpreted it as a degenerated random variable. What exactly do you mean with $P$ and $P(a)$? It is not unthinkable that your notations are not familiar to me.

Comment: @drhab The question is: Let $A$ and $B$ random variables, independent of each other and uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Define a new random variable $X = AB$. Find the probability density function for $X$.

Comment: @KennyWong Thank you.

Comment: Yes, @KennyWong got what I would like to ask

Answer (score 3):

I think your equation is correct.

Let's do the $b$ integral first, treating $a$ as a constant. If we perform the change of variables $u = ab$, we get
$$ \int_0^1 \delta(x - ab) \ db = \int_0^a \delta (x - u) \  \frac{du}{a} = \begin{cases} \frac 1 a & 0 \leq x \leq a \\ 0 & {\rm otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
Now, we need to do the $a$ integral. Since the answer to the previous integral is non-zero only for $a \geq x$, the limits on this integral should be $x \leq a \leq 1$:
$$ \int_x^1 \frac 1 a \ da=-\ln x,$$
which is the answer you want!